# How to read and write simultaneously from excel?

Tags: java, selenium

How to read and write simultaneously from excel? Scenario: Search "Facebook","Yahoo" in google search bar and write the title. For Both reading data and writing the title same excel should be used. Currently using Apache POI for file-handling.

Comment: We are not a coding service. Have you tried anything yet? Read the javadocs on Apache POI?

Comment: Hi..I have tried many times.Yet unable to do.Tried @Dataproviders, fileinputstream and Fileoutputstream. On individual files I am able to perform read and write operations. But unable to do both the operations simultaneously on single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read excel cell data use smth like this:

```
File excel = null;
FileInputStream file = null;

try {
    excel = new File(dir + "\\" + filename + ".xls");
    file = new FileInputStream(excel);

    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            // Cell data logic
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fn) {
    fail(fn.getMessage());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    file.close();
}
```

How to write date here is a good example: [click](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-write-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi)